# Classify the singularity of the function $f(z)=\frac{1}{z-\sin z}$ at the origin

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity-theory

> Classify the singularity of the function $f(z)=\frac{1}{z-\sin z}$ at
>   the origin.

Honnestly, I don't know what I have to do on this problem. I know we could develop $z-\sin z = \sum_{k \geq 1} \frac{(-1)^n z^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} = 0$.

Is anyone could give me more informations how to solve it?

Comment: Use $z - \sin z \approx {1 \over 3!} z^3$ to guess and then verify your guess.

Comment: @copper.hat Could you explain in details how you obtain $z-\sin(z) \approx \frac{z^3}{6}$? It is probably a silly question, but sometime I need a bit more explication (I have 13 years old).

Comment: Are you familiar with Taylor series? (I am surprised that you are dealing with singularities and haven't encountered the Taylor series of $\sin$.)

Comment: Yes I am, but I don't know how to find the good $k$ for $(z-z_0)^k$ such that $\lim_{z\to 0} \frac{(z-z_0)^k}{z-\sin(z)} = $ the order of our zero. Could you explain this part?

Comment: First you need to guess  that there is a pole of order 3 at $z_0 = 0$. That uses Taylor series. Then check that $\lim_{z \to  0} z^3 f(z)$ exists (and is non zero). But the 3 comes from the guess. Generally the Taylor series is a good indicator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the Taylor expansion of $\sin(z)$, we find that near $z=0$, $$z-\sin(z) \approx \frac{x^3}{6}.$$ So it is a third order pole at $z=0$. Indeed, multiply by $z^3$ and you will see that there is no long a pole there since $$\lim_{z\to 0} \frac{z^3}{z-\sin(z)} = 6.$$

Comment: I'm not sure poles of order greater than one can be named "removable": it is a pole of order three, in contrast with a *removable* pole (no order attached) like $\;z=0\;$ in $\;\frac{\sin z}z\;$, or an essential singularity.

Comment: In fact, *removable* goes along *singularity*, only. Pole and essential singularity are reserved. I believe, for non-removable singularities.

Comment: @User8128 Correction : $z-\sin(z) \approx \frac{z^3}{6}.$

Comment: Thank you all for your notes! I haven't taken complex analysis in several years so I had forgotten the vocabulary. I'll make an edit.

Comment: @User8128 Could you explain in details how you obtain $z-\sin(z) \approx \frac{z^3}{6}$?